# How to search specified objects from a jsonb column using querydsl in java

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, querydsl

In my postgresql, I have a table in which there is a column of type jsonb. This is my java class of that table:

```
@Table(schema = "public", name = "vw_user_site_role_permission")
@Data
@Entity
@TypeDef(
    name = "json",
    typeClass = JsonType.class
)
public class ViewUserSiteRolePermission extends AuditableEntity{

@Column(name = "user_site_id")
private Long userSiteId;

@Column(name = "user_role_id")
private Long userRoleId;

@Column(name = "user_id")
private Long userId;

@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "site_id")
private Long siteId;

@Column(name = "site_name")
private String siteName;

@Column(name = "code")
private String code;

@Column(name = "role_id")
private Long roleId;

@Column(name = "role_name")
private String roleName;

@Column(name = "permission_group_id")
private Long permissionGroupId;

@Column(name = "title")
private String title;

@Type(type = "json")
@Column(name = "permission", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
private JsonNode permission;
}
```

Now everything works good for other objects but i have to implement search on a field which is present in jsonb object.

I am using querydsl in my repository,

```
@Repository
public interface ViewUserSiteRolePermissionRepository extends 
JpaRepository<ViewUserSiteRolePermission, Long>, 
QuerydslPredicateExecutor<ViewUserSiteRolePermission> {
}
```

This is my method to implement filtering and searching on other objects:

```
@Override
public Page<ViewUserSiteRolePermission> getALLViewUserSiteRolePermission(List<Long> userIds, 
List<Long> userRoleIds, List<Long> siteIds, Long roleId, String search,String permissions, 
Pageable pageable) {
    BooleanBuilder filter = new BooleanBuilder();

    if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(userIds)) {
        filter.and(QViewUserSiteRolePermission.viewUserSiteRolePermission.userId.in(userIds));
    }

    if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(userRoleIds)) {         
filter.and(QViewUserSiteRolePermission.viewUserSiteRolePermission.userRoleId.in(userRoleIds));
    }

    if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(siteIds)) {
        filter.and(QViewUserSiteRolePermission.viewUserSiteRolePermission.siteId.in(siteIds));
    }

    if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(roleId)) {
        filter.and(QViewUserSiteRolePermission.viewUserSiteRolePermission.roleId.eq(roleId));
    }

    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(search)) {

        BooleanBuilder booleanBuilder = new BooleanBuilder();
        Arrays.asList(search.split(" ")).forEach(nm ->
                booleanBuilder.or(QViewUserSiteRolePermission.viewUserSiteRolePermission.siteName.containsIgnoreCase(nm))
        );
        filter.and(booleanBuilder);
    }

    return viewUserSiteRolePermissionRepository.findAll(filter, pageable);
}
```

Now how to apply filter on jsonb object using this approach?

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately querydsl can't access fields inside your jsonb object, just the object as a whole. But there is a way around. You can write a native query inside your repository and access it that way. Let's assume your field inside your permission object is called 'permissionTitle'.

Repo:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

@Repository public interface ViewUserSiteRolePermissionRepository extends  JpaRepository<ViewUserSiteRolePermission, Long>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<ViewUserSiteRolePermission> {

@Query(
      value =
          "SELECT * "
        + "FROM view_user_site_role_permission "
        + "WHERE CAST(permission ->> 'permissionTitle' AS VARCHAR) = ?1",
      nativeQuery = true)
List<ViewUserSiteRolePermission> findByPermissionTitle(final String permissionTitle);
}
```

And now inside your `getALLViewUserSiteRolePermission` function you can do something like this:

```
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(permissionTitle)) {
 final List<ViewUserSiteRolePermission> found = this.viewUserSiteRolePermissionRepository.findByPermissionTitle(permissionTitle);
 filter.and(QViewUserSiteRolePermission.viewUserSiteRolePermission.in(found);
}
```